# Minus character in swift (unable to read data)

Tags: swift, xcode

Faced some strange thing. Got the expression:

```
UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "kpk_name") as? String ?? "-"
```

When preference doesn't exist I'm expected to get String `"-"`, but result is "unable to read data".

If I'll change if null part of expression to any other String, everything works fine. (e.x. ... `as? String ?? "\u{2212}"`).

So I know how to solve the problem, but I'm interesting why this happens?

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful.

Comment: @MartinR I've edited my question

Comment: oh... seems this is problem with xcode... when i'm looking at var by debugger - "unable to read data", but print give me expected result

Comment: What is result? Can you update you question on  how you were getting the result from this expression?